# Sol 8.6.0 Admin UI not fully functional

Tags: solr

I have Solr 8.2.0 running without any issues.  I have just downloaded Sol 8.6.0 and once I access the admin UI after starting solr 8.6.0, the UI offers limited functionality.  Any option that I select from the left menu, e.g., Logging, Core Admin, Java Properties, etc. takes me back to the Dashboard. I am unable to add any cores since selecting Core Admin takes me back to the Dashboard option.

Any advice on what could possibly be wrong?  I am using jre1.8.0_221 version.

Comment: What does your Solr log say? It seems like your instance isn't running as it should; also, check the console error log in your browser under developer tools, since the interface is a javascript interface and any errors regarding the interface would be shown there.

Comment: It turned out it was a browser issue.  After resetting Chrome to default setting, the issue is resolved.  Thanks for your input.